# Purely resistive AC circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance

Is it possible to have a purely resistive RC circuit?

> Recently came across a question: A 130Ω resistor and a 40μF capacitor are connected in series to an AC source of frequency ω. For the combination to be purely resistive what must be the value of frequency ω?

Is this question right or are they missing the info about inductance?

Comment: Can you provide the book & page (preferably a link to an online example if possible) ?

Comment: well unfortunately i cant cause it was an online test i had today

Answer (score 1):

A resistor and capacitor in series would be "purely resistive" only if the angular frequency $\omega$ is $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The only way the circuit can look "purely resistive" is if there is an inductor in series with the capacitor and resistor and where the frequency is such that the inductive reactance equals the capacitive reactance, or

$$\omega L=\frac{1}{\omega C}$$

$$\omega=\frac{1}{\sqrt {LC}}$$

where $\omega$ is now the resonant frequency.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. The question is wrong I suppose ?

Comment: Well,   in the limit  $\omega \rightarrow \infty$  the capacitative reactance is zero.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft But the frequency can never really be infinite, so there will always be some capacitive reactance, even if it is very small.

Comment: @wanderer Yes I believe it is wrong, unless you're willing to accept that the frequency can be infinite, as suggested by CarlWitthoft. You can see my comment to him.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help i shall raise up this point and let yall know soon

Comment: @wanderer I would add what would be the practical application if the frequency had to be infinite? On the other hand, RL resonance has many applications.

Comment: @BobD  The point of the test question could be to see if the  testee understands limits

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Could be, but it's still speculation